# Unable to extend display using WindowKey+P in win 7

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I am unable to extend my monitor display to another monitor using windowKey+P shortcut. I also tried running displayswitch.exe from run command but nothing appears.
BTW, i am using standard vga adapter for my graphic driver because i couldn't find any suitable graphic driver for my HP 250 G4 notebook (which seems to be AMD Radeon R5 M330 but only 64 bit driver is available on official site and i have 32 bit win 7 so that driver doesn't work) Is it the reason?
Need help. Appreciate it. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is no graphics card driver, we need to install the correct graphics driver. According to my query, for AMD Radeon R5 M330, AMD official website only provides 64-bit operating system graphics driver, so it is recommended that you install 64-bit operating system, and then try the 64-bit graphics driver on the official website.

Comment: But i need to use that data management tool which doesn't support 64 bit so i have to install 32 bit windows.